# Как отфильтровать список

Tags: python, pandas, list

В моей задаче у меня получился список с именами людей. Каждый элемент списка с именами показывает кто с кем общается. Для примера, список ниже:

```
friendships=[['Ann', 'Jhon'],['Fred', 'Hugh'],['Eric', 'James'],['James','Eric'],['Hugh','Fred'],['Jhon', 'Ann'],['Fred','Hugh','Gregory'],['Hugh', 'Fred','Gregory'],['Fred', 'Hugh', 'Gregory', 'Norman'],['Norman', 'Hugh', 'Fred', 'Gregory']]
```

На выходе:

```
[['Ann', 'Jhon'],
 ['Fred', 'Hugh'],
 ['Eric', 'James'],
 ['James', 'Eric'],
 ['Hugh', 'Fred'],
 ['Jhon', 'Ann'],
 ['Fred', 'Hugh', 'Gregory'],
 ['Hugh', 'Fred', 'Gregory'],
 ['Fred', 'Hugh', 'Gregory', 'Norman'],
 ['Norman', 'Hugh', 'Fred', 'Gregory']]
```

Мне надо его отфильтровать так, что те элементы, которые уже присутствуют в други (повторы), удалить их. На выходе мне надо такое:

```
[['Ann', 'Jhon'], ['James', 'Eric'], ['Fred', 'Hugh', 'Gregory', 'Norman']]
```

Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: unique = set(friendships)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этим свойством обладает `set` - множество не имеет повторений

```
unique = set(friendships)
```

Хотя в вашем случае  `['Fred', 'Hugh']`  равно  `['Hugh', 'Fred']` как я понимаю, поэтому надо сперва преобразовать исходный список, упорядочивая данные например по алфавиту...
Можно было бы записать код так:

```
unique = set([set(el) for el in friendships ])
```

но он не будет работать, так как `set`  можно брать только от хешируемых объектов, а `set` таким не является))

Решением является такая строка:

```
zz = set(tuple(sorted(el)) for el in friendships)
```

и результат:

```
zz
Out[11]: 
{('Ann', 'Jhon'),
 ('Eric', 'James'),
 ('Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh'),
 ('Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh', 'Norman'),
 ('Fred', 'Hugh')}
```

если же надо вернуться к списку списков а не кортежей, то тогда так:

```
lst = [list(z) for z in set(tuple(sorted(el)) for el in friendships)]
```

с результатом

```
[['Fred', 'Hugh'],
 ['Eric', 'James'],
 ['Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh'],
 ['Ann', 'Jhon'],
 ['Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh', 'Norman']]
```

**Итого ваше решение в одну строку:**

```
 lst = [list(z) for z in set(tuple(sorted(el)) for el in friendships)]
 print(lst)
```

дает

```
[['Fred', 'Hugh'], ['Eric', 'James'], ['Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh'], ['Ann', 'Jhon'], ['Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh', 'Norman']]
```

Добавлю, что это решение будет быстрее чем использование циклов.

С учетом уточнений задачи окончательное решение может выглядеть так:

```
zz = set(tuple(sorted(el)) for el in friendships)
zzz = zz.copy()    #  делаем копию множества для удалений, т.к. удалять из множества для цикла опасно
for el in zz:
    for elem in zz - {el}:     #    то есть перебираем множество без самого 'el'
        if set(el) <= set(elem):     #  если элементы set(el)  содержатся в set(elem)  элементах то удаляем
            zzz.remove(el)
            break
print(zzz)
{('Ann', 'Jhon'), ('Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh', 'Norman'), ('Eric', 'James')}
```

Post Scriptum: Как указал  Stanislav Volodarskiy,  в Python есть тип `frozenset`, который может быть элементами множества.   Тогда вместо

```
zz = set(tuple(sorted(el)) for el in friendships)
```

можно написать

```
 zz = set(frozenset(el) for el in friendships)
```

Но тогда на выходе у вас получится сет фрозенсетов, которые возможно придется все равно превращать в списки или кортежи....

Comment: спасибо за помощь! Есть один момент: ['Fred', 'Hugh'] также есть и в ['Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh'] и в ['Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh', 'Norman']. А нужно чтобы остался только элемент, который бы содержал все эти имена, т.е.  ['Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh', 'Norman']. Я уже думаю может через графы это надо делать

Comment: уточните ваш вопрос этим замечанием.
Да графы можно, но можно проще сча покажу

Comment: вопрос такой, как сделать, чтобы ['Fred', 'Hugh'] и ['Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh'] ушли из списка, а остался вместо них ['Fred', 'Gregory', 'Hugh', 'Norman']. Т.к в этом элементе списка уже присутствуют эти имена, ну т.е оставить самый полный элемент списка с именами. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: если я чем-то помог  - поставьте палец вверх на ответе)

Comment: `set` -> `frozenset`

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
s = set()
f = []
for l in sorted(friendships, key=len, reverse=True):
    if not set(l).issubset(s):
        s.update(l)
        f.append(l)
print(f)
```

Вывод:

```
[['Fred', 'Hugh', 'Gregory', 'Norman'], ['Ann', 'Jhon'], ['Eric', 'James']]
```

Comment: `(('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a')) -> [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c')]`